# Post to/for_the difference?

Tags: prepositions, indirect-objects

I just saw a sentence which made me think, consult my dictionary, and finally form a question that I can't find an answer to.

What's the difference between these two sentences:

> I'll post those letters **for** you.
>
> I'll post those letters **to** you.

Comment: If you post some letters ***for*** someone, you're saving them the trouble of posting those letters themselves (letters which they probably wrote themselves; certainly, letters which they are responsible for posting). If you post letters ***to*** someone, you hope they will eventually be delivered ***to*** that person.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Technically, "for you" **can** mean the same as "to you"...

Comment: @Catija: I'm not sure what you mean by "technically" there. If you do something *for* someone, it's practically always either *on their behalf* or *for their benefit*. In principle I suppose a rather irritating customer service rep might say *I've got some letters here that I think you should read. I'll post them for you* (so you can receive them and have the benefit of reading them) But it's a somewhat contrived context (*and* a tiresome way of speaking, imho).

Comment: The local dialect where I live is actually potentially confusing in this regard because when someone asks for a favour they're more likely to say "Kin ye dae this tae ma?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can mean significantly different things:

> I'll post those letters for you.

This can be slightly ambiguous... while it **can** mean the same as "to you", it can also mean that you are volunteering to take letters to the post office **for** someone. You are doing them a favor. You don't know who the letters are directed to but you're going to mail them for the person you're speaking to.

I would argue that this second meaning is *more often* the implied meaning.

> I'll post those letters to you.

This means that you have some letters that are addressed **to** the person you are speaking with that they are supposed to receive but you have not yet mailed/posted them.

So, if your intent is to say you're sending the letters on their behalf, I recommend using "for" and if you're sending the letters that are directed to them, I recommend using "to".

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has written some letters, and you are planning to go out, you might offer to put the letters into the post for them:

> I'll post those letters for you

If you want to send several letters to somebody, you would say to them:

> I'll post those letters to you